# Assembly: What is ntdll.7C910208?

Tags: assembly, x86

I always seem to find that the ebp register ends up being set to the value ntdll.7C910208. I looked up what is exactly at this location and found that it was the statment:

db ff

It's just a declaration of a byte with hex value ff. What is the significance of this? Why is this particular statement always associated with the EBP register?

Comment: How did you look up the location?

Comment: Just load ntdll.dll into Ollydbg

Answer (score 2):

Giving addresses in ntdll is useless if its been virtualized, ASLR will make sure of that.
Secondly you haven't really given much else info, such as, is this 32bit ntdll, WOW64 ntdll and what build of windows?

When is it set to this value, when you make any call into ntdll, or on a specific call? This is why you should provide a test case.

Going on the limited info provided, I'd assume its either the end or start of a global in ntdll.

Comment: 1. I tagged the post with "x86 assembly" so it should be clear this is 32 bit Windows NT 2. ntdll does not change over windows nt versions 3. I am examining a c program in assembly and attempting to figure out why ntdll was called for the purpose of allocating a new variable

Comment: @user1210446: 1. x86 could be WOW64 or 32bit (they are *not* the same dll) 2. yes it does, and you could be using windows 95 for all we know 3. unless you actually give something concrete, its impossible to give a decent answer, thats why a test case is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of MANY APIs that are in kernel32.dll.  Many of the API calls in windows are just wrappers for functions in ntdll.

> 1. I tagged the post with "x86 assembly" so it should be clear this is 32 bit Windows NT

x86 Covers Windows, Linux, MAC, and anything that has an INTEL chip 8086 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure but my guess it's a return value coming from a function called in ntdll.  This would make sense since 0xff is -1 and a common return value.